# Rails - Make MailChimp Hominid Gem, a background task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, mailchimp

I'm trying to make my Hominid call to MailChimp API, however without much success. My call looks like

```
h.list_subscribe(:user_list_id, params[:email], {'FNAME' => '', 'LNAME' => ''}, 'html', true, true, true, false)
```

where h is an object of Homind::API class. This object neither has a 'delay' method provided by delayed_job gem. It does not even have standard methods like 'class' or 'methods'. When, I create a custom job, it is not added to the job queue.

Explicity, setting the method to 'handle_asynchronously' results in a

```
can't convert nil into String
```

in

```
lib/delayed/yaml_ext.rb:16:in `value='
```

I'm guessing Delayed_Job cannot serialize the very stripped own Hominid::API object. Suggestions on how to go about this are most welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the answer was there all along.

When a custom job is created, it needs to loaded from a initializer so that it is available when delayed_job executes the job. A simple,

```
require 'my_custom_job_class'
```

in any of the initializers will do.

You can also find more info from [delayed_job wiki](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-jobs_are_silently_removed_from_the_database)